# How to fixed jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

[image: Please click here for image]

Please see attached screenshot. In this screenshot, the marquee is there but it's not working. I think it's conflicting with other scripts.

I am using below script in my page:

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery.webticker.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $("#webticker-update-example").webTicker({
    });
</script>
```

and this is another script. which conflicts with the marquee. when I comment out this code, then marquee work fine

```
( function($) {
    $(document) .ready(function(){
        $('nav#menu').mmenu();
    });
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: which script you have writen first in your page?

Comment: no i am asking which script code you have writen first (means: in order). 
First=> marquee script then navMenu script.

Comment: yes first marquee then navMenu, actually navMenu is in script file and marquee is in home page but marquee is first

Answer (score 0):

As i don't know your full code, whatever you have writen in script. This should not happen, but when happens it's very critical to solve in original way. You must done something wrong. Might possible somehow you have loaded **jQuery library** two times or many more reason.

The another way to solve this problem is using `noConflict` in your script.

Syntax is `var jq = $.noConflict();` and after then you need to use `jq` instead of `$`. 
For more information you can use following link::

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp

Comment: It must work, may you have made something wrong. Need to show full code. And update your question